# calling a test case within a test case in SOAP UI

Tags: properties, soapui, ready-api

I am trying to call a test case within a test case using SOAP UI Pro. I created a reusable test case to generate a random VIN and intend to call this test case within other test case where applicable. I used property transfer, but I am unable to set the property in the test case to the value being returned.

I created a test case, wrote a groovy script, added a property to the test case and added a property transfer.[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Opij7.png)

I have been unable to set the property vin (highlighted) as shown in the picture. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works with "DataGen" option.Lets say you have 2 testcases TC1 and TC2 Right click on TC1-> choose DataGen and add a property, write the groovy script for generating the random VIN. 
Go to the TC2 where you want to reuse the VIN, right click on the property name and click on "get data"  ->TC1->property name.

https://www.soapui.org/data-driven-tests/reference/datagen-teststep.html